# How to configure 3 vlans on HP Procurve 2920 switch and Gateway is a CISCO router

Tags: networking, routing, router, switch, gateway

New to networking.  Have a procurve 2920 24 port switch that I need to configure.  New to netowrking and not sure how to do it.

Need to create a Data VLAN, VOICE VLAN, WIRLESS VLAN for business and WIRELESS VLAN for guest.

Switch will use a CISCO router as its gateway.

IP Address to use 192.168.3.1 for GW
IP Address 192.168.3.2 is for switch
IP Address 192.168.3.3 is for ShoreTel voice switch.

I have config t the switch default vlan with IP Address 192.168.3.2

I have created the vlans 120 untagged for data, vlan 130 tagged for voice, vlan 140 tagged for wireless, vlan 150 tagged for wireles guest.  I have moved ports 11 through 24 into the vans.

What are my next steps.

Comment: You only tag VLANs on a trunk interface. Do not tag on access interfaces. You will need to trunk all the VLANs to the router, and you will need to create subinterfaces on the router for the VLANs.

Comment: Thanks Ron, I thought if I wanted to plug in a VOIP phone into any interface I would have to tagged all the vlans for voice same with wirless.  That way when I plug in a phone into interface 11 - 24 it would be tagged for voice traffic. Also since its a 24 port switch and all the vlans has the port 24 assigned to it can I trunk port 24 which would allow all the vlans access to the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are done with the Switch, you will identify the port that will connect to Cisco router. The port will be configured as Trunk Port.

On the Cisco router, you will configure the connected port as trunk as well. Something on these lines.

```
configure terminal

interface <type> x

no ip address

interface <type> x.120

description DATA

encapsulation dot1q 120 native

interface <type> x.130

description VOICE

encapsulation dot1q 130
```

and so on. You can also add IP addresses to each sub interface.